# why is 123.56 - 62.12 = 61.440000000000005

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy, subtraction, floating-point-precision

I am just starting with python and was running through a tutorial [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Hello,_World)

Running the exmamples, I was surprised to find
    print("123.56 - 62.12 =", 123.56 - 62.12)

To come out as
    123.56 - 62.12 = 61.440000000000005

I am running python v3.3.0 Ran it in an online interpreter [here](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/) and got the same

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  It should be required reading for everyone on this site.

Comment: jwodder, I've seen that article, but I think it's a little hard to read and I don't see anything about a simple subtraction in that article, mostly division rounding things